# Meteor Call returning 404 Method Not Found

Tags: javascript, meteor

```
        Meteor.call('create_question', title, content, function(error, result) {
            console.log('create_question error ' + error);
            console.log('create_question result ' + result);

            if (error) {

            } else {
                console.log('Your question was submitted');
            }
        });
```

This is my call Meteor call on the client.

and I've got this in the server.

```
Meteor.methods({
    create_question: function(question_title, question_content) {
// does stuff   
    },

});
```

But for some reason I keep getting Method is not found. Anyone know what's wrong? I've got the Meteor.methods in the server folder and the call in the client folder.

Answer (score 2):

The method `create_question` should be defined on **both** the client and the server.

You can use [`this.isSimulation`](http://docs.meteor.com/#method_issimulation) to figure-out whether the Method is being executed on the server or the client (as a stub).

Comment: Why is that so? I always define my methods inside `server` directory and never had similar problems.

Comment: @HubertOG True, the documentation seems to concur: `You don't have to define a stub for your method if you don't want to.`. I recall having to define a stub but I guess I'll probe a little deeper.

Comment: Yeah, I've got this working with other methods. I'll look into it deeper myself. Might be method specific, i'll have to look into the contents.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that another method being called within your `create_question` method isn't defined.

That was my problem, but the error message still says that the `create_question` method is the one that's not defined.